# Refactoring my simple model-view-presenter architecture

Tags: java

My application uses a simple Model-View-Presenter architecture and uses the following classes and interface:

**Presenter:**

```
public abstract class Presenter<V> {

    private V view;

    public final void setView(V view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    protected final V getView() {
        return this.view;
    }
}
```

**View**

```
public abstract class View<V, P extends Presenter<V>> implements ViewAdapter<V> {

    private final P presenter;

    public View(P presenter) {
        this.presenter = presenter;
    }

    protected final P getPresenter() {
        return this.presenter;
    }

    void initialize() {
        this.getPresenter().setView(this.asView());
    }
}
```

**ViewAdapter**

```
interface ViewAdapter<T> {
    T asView();
}
```

The application is then wired up like this:

- A concrete `Presenter` is created.
- A concrete `View` is created, passing in the concrete `Presenter` as a constructor parameter.
- The `View` is initialised. During initialisation, the `View` calls the `asView` method to pass a view instance to the presenter.

Each concrete presenter in the application is parameterised with a view interface. Each concrete view class implements a view interface and can then pass itself to the presenter during initialisation and it is in this area that I am looking for advice.

The `ViewAdapter` interface exists solely to allow the concrete view to pass itself to the presenter via the `asView` method whilst maintaining type safety. My concrete views which derive from the View class are then forced to provide an implementation of the `asView` method in order to provide a view instance to the presenter that is of the correct type.

Every implementation looks the same:

```
@Override
public FooView asView() {
    return this; // this implements the FooView interface.
}
```

All this basically does is force 'this' to implement `FooView` as I am unable to express something like this:

```
// Example, not valid code, won't compile!
public abstract class View<V, P extends Presenter<V>> implements V {
}
```

Which would allow me to remove the `ViewAdapter` interface and pass the view to the presenter in the abstract `View` class like this, removing the redundancy:

```
void initialize() {
    this.getPresenter().setView(this);
}
```

Comment: I'm sure it's possible. We're not here to write code for you. We're just here to review your already existing code.

Comment: 1). this is actual code from an application I am writing. I have just stripped out the noise to demonstrate the actual problem. 2). I haven't asked anyone to write this for me. I am asking for guidance on factoring out the redundancy introduced with the `ViewAdapter` interface.

Comment: I apologize. I'm stupid! Retracted close vote.

Comment: try to use java generics constraints as  `Presenter<V extends View>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing this code a few times I've come to the conclusion that there is no way to express what I am trying to say in Java I.E the View class must implement an interface of type V as in the (illegal) snippet below.

```
public abstract class View<V, P extends Presenter<V>> implements V {
}
```

This leaves me with the following options:

1. Leave my code as is and accept the (minimal) redundancy.
2. Remove some of the generic parameters and accept that if I configure my application incorrectly I will get an invalid cast exception.

Answer (score 1):

I tried it in an IDE and have some addition to the last comment. I agree that you should try

```
Presenter<V extends View>
```

plus I would add that you need to switch the signature to

```
public abstract class View<V, P extends Presenter>
```

from

```
public abstract class View<V, P extends Presenter<V>>
```

That is regarding to make it compile. Additionally, you can discard generics V since it is not used anymore in the View so the final signature would be:

```
public abstract class View<P extends Presenter>
```

Then you can get rid of ViewAdapter and the initialize method should work as you want it:

```
void initialize() {
    this.getPresenter().setView(this);
}
```